# Azure Function API -> Power platform custom connector

Tags: azure, rest, swagger, powerapps

I have followed this:
https://medium.com/faun/end-to-end-powerapps-with-custom-rest-api-c111aa95fa18
(and other guide online, and on docs.microsoft)
but I can't get by this error:
[image: Error-Pic]

Does anyone have any suggestions to what server are not connected?

Comment: Is the issue still persistent ? if yes,
Can you please take the decrypted fiddler trace, see/share the error if you find any & do you get any console error (F12) when you get the above error ? 
The error could help us understand better ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer to the API issue, but my solution was to make a PostMan Collection and import in Power app costumconnector.
That solved my problem.